# Windows 8 : Hook explorer.exe so that when PC startup, it will start the specified application and show the application's UI

Tags: windows-8, hook, explorer

Is it possible to Hook explorer.exe on Windows 8 so that when PC startup, it will startup the specified application and show the application's UI instead of showing the default UI of windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can replace the `Shell` registry key](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows7/AdminTips/Admin/ReplacingtheExplorerShellinWindows7.html) under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` to start a different UI.